# Calling a php function multiple times, to return a different variable each time

Tags: php, function

I have a few HTML pages, each with about 7 individual table headings on each pages. The table headers are generated from a MySQL database.

Each page can have up to 7 different table headings.

I have an include file with a MySQL query (which is working fine for pages with only a single table heading) - this MySQL query accepts an argument ($table) to select the correct table form the database.

My function looks like this:

```
function getTable() {
          return $table;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
getTable('table_name');  // table_name is the name of the table I want.
```

So when my page loads, the function will be called multiple times and a different "table_name" will be passed to my include file each time using the $table variable.

However - I cannot get this to work at all.

I just get "Notice: Undefined variable: table in " from both the include file and the file containing the function.

What am I doing wrong?

***UPDATE***

If I add:

```
$table = "table_header1";
```

to the top of the file which contains the HTML - then this is passed to the include file.

But if I use the function (which is now in the include file) then the $table parameter is not passed.

Is this a global variable issue?

```
<?php
// top of file
$table = "table_header1";
include('header_inc.php');
// this works - the variable is passed to header.inc.php
?>

<?php
// top of file
include('header_inc.php');
getTable('table_header1');
echo $table;
// this ^^ does not work
?>
```

Comment: You need to define the argument parameter: `function getTable($table)`. Is the function really just going to return the same string as you pass to it?

Comment: @Magnus - yes I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Syed - that gives me the same error.

Comment: @Darshan - I already have a working MySQL query in my include file.

Comment: Now @Tony give us your full code over there so we can better understand what your problem.

Comment: I just tried to echo out $table from the include file - and the variable is blank, which explains the errors. I will try to summarise my code shortly. I suspect that what's happening is that include file is being processed before the $table variable is set - and hence it will not work like this?

Comment: Without knowing what your code actually looks like, it's totally and completely impossible for us to know what and where the error is. **Always** post the **actual** code.

Comment: Sorry - but I have ~400 lines of code for the tables and ~280 lines in my include file. I have established that the function is working, but the variable is not being passed to the include file. I moved the function to the include file *and* I am able to echo out $table from there - however it's just not getting passed to my query. At least with help from you guys, I have verified that my function is now correct and working - I'll try to tackle myself now.

Comment: I have updated the question with a little more info and tried to make the issue a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods should be like:

```
function getTable($tableName) {
      $table = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
      return $table;
}
```

Further formatting has to be done by you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you just pass the parameter:

```
function getTable($table = null) {
  return $table;
}
```

Instead of a static variable, use a function parameter with a default value.